# Getting Error ';' expected java

Tags: java, arrays

I don't know what's the error in my code. I just copy it from the tutorial and it has an error but in the tutorial it's perfectly running here's the code.

```
class arraye {
public static void main(String[] args) {

int[] testResult;
testResult = new int[30];

testResult[0] = 87;

String[] DaysOfTheWeek = { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday, "Friday" };

System.out.print("Test Result: " + testResult[0]);
System.out.print("Day: " + DaysOfTheWeek[2]);


}
}
```

Comment: What is the error? Aside from your title, you are missing a description, stack trace, or even a vague guess. Please add more information.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a close quote here on Thursday,

```
String[] DaysOfTheWeek = { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday, "Friday" };
```

should be

```
String[] DaysOfTheWeek = { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday" };
```

Comment: Thanks you! Im sorry I didnt see that

Answer (score 2):

This would solve your problem:

```
String[] DaysOfTheWeek = { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday" };
```

Issue was Quoted string not terminated properly. So, it would consider "`Thursday ,`" (Thursday with comma and space) as one value and `Friday` would be hanging around not as a string but as some undefined variable. Since it is syntactically incorrect, you would be getting the exception.

Answer (score 2):

Just look in your DaysOfTheWeek array. You have missed a double quote at the end of Thursday like

String[] DaysofTheWeek = {"", "Wednesday", "Thursday, "Friday"};

Correction:

```
String[] DaysOfTheWeek = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"};
```